# Executing command on doubleclick with WPF NotifyIcon

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

After many days of trial and error with [WPF NotifyIcon](http://www.hardcodet.net/wpf-notifyicon) I've finally managed to hide my main window when I want to and I'm also able to bring it back using a context menu attached to the icon. However, I can't seem to use the same commands I'm using in the context menu for the doubleclick property for the notifyicon.

As per the tutorial that comes with WPF NotifyIcon I added the command I wanted in MainWindow.xaml like so:

```
<Grid.Resources>
    <Commands:ShowWindowCommand
        x:Key="ShowTheWindow" />
</Grid.Resources>
```

I then created the taskbaricon, also in MainWindow.xaml, thusly:

```
<tb:TaskbarIcon
      IconSource="/Images/Error.ico"
      LeftClickCommand="{StaticResource ShowTheWindow}" >>>THIS DOES NOT WORK<<<
      LeftClickCommandParameter="{Binding}">
            <tb:TaskbarIcon.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <MenuItem Header="Hide"
                                Command="{StaticResource ShowTheWindow}" >>> THIS WORKS PERFECTLY <<<
                                CommandParameter="{Binding}" 
                                Visibility="{Binding Path=IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource booleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
```

And here's the function which I copied from one of the example projects:

```
namespace StreamRecorder2.Commands
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Shows the main window.
    /// </summary>
    public class ShowWindowCommand : CommandBase<ShowWindowCommand>
    {
        public override void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            GetTaskbarWindow(parameter).Show();
            GetTaskbarWindow(parameter).WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
            CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
        }


        public override bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            Window win = GetTaskbarWindow(parameter);
            return win != null && !win.IsVisible;
        }
    }
}
```

The command I want works perfectly from the context menu, but when I add the same command to the doubleclick property of the taskbaricon it doesn't do anything. I added a breakpoint in "ShowWindowCommand" which triggers when I execute the command via the context menu. But it does not when I doubleclick the icon.

As you can probably tell, I'm doing a lot of google-copy-paste-google here so I'm a bit lost as to where to even start to figure this out or what other information you might need.

Comment: I am not very familiar with <tb:TaskbarIcon> control. But If you we're to ask on how we can bind a command to double click, I would say, you can always try the following: 1. By extending the taskbar control and adding a dependency property, 2. Creating an attached property, 3. Using xaml behaviors. If this is what you mean, I can give you an example of attaching a command when you double click, let's say, an ellipse or a button.

Comment: Did you set the `MenuActivation` property of the tb:TaskbarIcon to `LeftOrDoubleClick`?

Comment: @leetibbett, that property only seems to be related to activating the popup menu. The popup menu works fine and I can execute the command from there. But doubleclicking the icon and having it activate the same command does not work.

Comment: @LawrenceA.Contreras, I'm sorry, I should've been more clear about the control. I've added a link to the custom control I'm using to the original post at the top. I don't know if that would change your reply or not.

Comment: There's [an example of a custom double-click command](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36468/WPF-NotifyIcon#commands), if that is the same as your example then it's the control.